# Как отобразить меню компонента Joomla на всех view

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, joomla, joomla3

Пишу для себя компонент Joomla с названием Ypay. Файловая структура как на скриншоте https://i.stack.imgur.com/B098N.png. И вот скриншот самого меню https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UiC2.png Каждый пункт меню - это будет своя model и свой views. Но как отобразить это меню на всех views?

```
код меню в models/ypay.php 
class YPayModelYPay extends JModelItem
{
protected $messages;

protected function getMenuFromDb()
{
    $db    = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('menu_name, parent_menu_name, has_child_menu');
    $query->from('#__ypay_mainmenu');
    $db->setQuery((string) $query);
    $messages = $db->loadAssocList();
    return $messages;
}

public function getMenuNameMsg()
{
    if (!isset($this->message))
    {
        $this->message = $this->getMenuFromDb();
    }
    return $this->message;
}
}

код меню в views/ypay.html.php
class YPayViewYPay extends JViewLegacy
{
    function display($tpl = null)
{
    // Assign data to the view

    $this->msg = $this->get('MenuNameMsg');

 // Check for errors.
    if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) {
        JLog::add(implode('<br />', $errors), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');

        return false;
    }
    $this->showMainMenu();
    // Display the view
    parent::display($tpl);
}

public function showMainMenu()
{
    foreach ($this->msg as $item => $value) {
        if ($value['has_child_menu'] == '0' && $value['parent_menu_name'] == 
'0') {
            echo "<a href=''><input type='button'  style='padding-bottom: 
5px;' class='btn btn-primary btn-ypay' id='projects-btn' value=" . 
$value['menu_name'] . "></a>";
        } elseif ($value['has_child_menu'] == '1') {
            $liItem = [];
            $parentMenu = $value['menu_name'];
            echo '<div class="dropdown" style="display: inline; margin-
right: 5px;"><button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
data-toggle="dropdown">' . $value['menu_name'] .' '. '<span class="caret">
</span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu">';
            foreach ($this->msg as $key => $data) {
                if ($parentMenu == $data['parent_menu_name']) {
                    $liItem[] = $data['menu_name'];
                }
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <= count($liItem) - 1; $i++) {
                echo '<li><a href="/ypay/index.php?
option=com_ypay&view=workers">' . $liItem[$i] . '</a></li>';
                if ($liItem[$i] !== $liItem[count($liItem) - 1]) echo '<li 
class="divider" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #007bcc; margin: 2px 1px 2px 
2px;"></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul></div>';
            unset($liItem);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Вопрос в том, как отобразить это меню на всех views (workers, orders и т.д.)?

P.S. Не судите строго - только учусь.

Сделал вот так, файл views/workers/view.hmtl.php

```
    class YPayViewWorkers extends JViewLegacy

    {

    protected $MainMenuItems;

    // Overwriting JView display method
    function display($tpl = null)
    {

        //  sets default model
        $this->setModel($this->getModel('workers'), true);
//  sets second model & uses 'JModelLegacy,' contrary to documentation
        $this->setModel(JModelLegacy::getInstance('YPay', 'YPayModel'));
//  assigns array from the second model to 'MainMenuItems' there is no '$' sign used.
        $this->MainMenuItems = $this->get('MenuNameMsg', 'YPay');


        // Assign data to the view
        $this->msg = $this->get('WorkersMsg');
        $this->msg2 = $this->get('WorkersInputMsg');

        $this->showMainMenu($this->MainMenuItems);


        // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);
    }

    public function showMainMenu($arr)
    {
        foreach ($arr as $item => $value) {
            if ($value['has_child_menu'] == '0' && $value['parent_menu_name'] == '0') {
                echo "<a href=''><input type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-ypay' id='projects-btn' value=" . $value['menu_name'] . "></a>";
            } elseif ($value['has_child_menu'] == '1') {
                $liItem = [];
                $parentMenu = $value['menu_name'];
                echo '<div class="dropdown"><button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">' . $value['menu_name'] .' '. '<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu">';
                foreach ($arr as $key => $data) {
                    if ($parentMenu == $data['parent_menu_name']) {
                        $liItem[] = $data['menu_name'];
                    }
                }

                for ($i = 0; $i <= count($liItem) - 1; $i++) {
                    echo '<li><a href="/ypay/index.php?option=com_ypay&view=workers">' . $liItem[$i] . '</a></li>';
                    if ($liItem[$i] !== $liItem[count($liItem) - 1]) echo '<li class="divider" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #007bcc; margin: 2px 1px 2px 2px;"></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul></div>';
                unset($liItem);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

норм так будет?

Comment: куча вопросов собралось сразу...  "Каждый пункт меню - это будет своя model " зачем для каждого пункта меню - своя модель ?? Ответ (без примера) на ваш вопрос---- подключите модель отдельно в каждый view.html.php и там вызывайте функцию из модели, котрая получает элементы определённого меню, что в свою очередь можно получить, например, в default.php вашего компонента...
з.ы  я так стараюсь вас натолкнуть на правильный путь (на мысль)

Comment: дописал выше. так нормально будет?